# Embeddable, runtime Java object inspector for debugging

Tags: java, debugging, reflection

I'm looking for a lightweight way of embedding some GUI-based object inspection facilities in a Java application.

1. Ideally it would be something like the variable inspector in the Eclipse debugger, which lets you see all the fields of a given object instance, and drill down to inspect fields contained within these. Doesn't have to be pretty, just needs to have a way to inspect the value of all fields
2. I *don't* just want to use a debugger: this idea is that the facility can be used on the application at runtime, allowing for quick diagnostics without restarting the application.
3. It needs to be pretty lightweight: since this is meant to be embedded in a deployed application, I don't want to pull in a whole load of extra dependencies. So Swing would be OK, but pulling in a whole native widget library would be out of the question (sorry, no SWT....)
4. It needs to be able to inspect an arbitrary Java/JVM object (presumably via reflection)

Does anyone know a tool like this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know "ready" framework but can recommend you to either use JDPA directly or use one of libraries that are using byte code engineering done at runtime. For example take a look on [java-interceptor](https://code.google.com/p/java-interceptor/) that can help you if you can control the code you want to interspect.